# Alternate code for "if else" in my code

Tags: javascript

Below given was my javaScript code. 
Condition is, If I give a word like hello. the image for a hello should be displayed or if I give facebook, the image for that has to be displayed likewise for many words, the mentioned image has to be displayed.. But here in my code condition gets failed after first time and image is not displaying for the second word.
Help me with the alternate code for the above mentioned problem

```
        var anu = document.getElementById("display");
        var a= document.getElementById("final_span").textContent;
            console.log(linebreak(interim_transcript));
        if(a.search("hello") || a.search("facebook")){
        if(linebreak(interim_transcript) == "hello"){
          anu.innerHTML="<img src=hello.jpg>";
        }
        else if(linebreak(interim_transcript) == "facebook"){
           anu.innerHTML="<img src=facebook.jpg>";
        }
         else if(linebreak(interim_transcript) == "hi"){
           anu.innerHTML="<img src=hi.jpg>";
        }
         else if(linebreak(interim_transcript) == "doll"){
           anu.innerHTML="<img src=doll.jpg>";
        }
```

Comment: We have no idea what `linebreak` does or returns. For all we know it could return `'otherstring'`.

Comment: Is `"<img src='"  + linebreak(interim_transcript) +  ".jpg'>"` an option?

Comment: Thank you. But have tried this if else already but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

If the value returned by `linebreak` and image name are same you can use

```
anu.innerHTML = '<img src="' + linebreak(interim_transcript) + '">';
```

---

Otherwise you can use a object where you can specify the image name

```
var obj = {
    hello: "hello.jpg",
    facebook: 'facebook.jpg',
    hi: 'hi.jpg'
}


var anu = document.getElementById("display");
var a = document.getElementById("final_span").textContent;

if (a.search("hello") || a.search("facebook")) {
    var lb = linebreak(interim_transcript);
    if (obj[lb]) {
        anu.innerHTML = '<img src="' + obj[lb] + '">';
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of having an object, you can refactor this more by using a simple array with values, also `.jpg` can be removed from all and placed in `img` directly

Comment: You'd probably want to credit @Vohuman with the first part of your answer.

Comment: @Mr.Alien how do you use a simple array?

Comment: @ArunPJohny `var obj = ['hello', 'facebook', 'hi']; obj.indexOf(lb);` ?

Comment: @Mr.Alien that assumes both the image name and image names are same then why do we have to do this... `anu.innerHTML = '<img src="' + linebreak(interim_transcript) + '">';` should be enough